# Add double quotes to some part of a dynamic string

Tags: java, json

I have a String. I am converting to JSonObject then to JSONArray. But the string is not a perfect JSONObject. I am trying to convert it to a perfect JSONOBject by adding double quotes to ids and States but i am not sure how to do that. Need some suggestions please.

```
String jsonString = "{
\"userDetails\": {
    ids: [\"1\", \"2\"],
    States: [\"TX\", \"PA\"]
}
}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject("userDetails");
String array = obj1.getJSONArray("HE_SUBJECT").toString();
```

But here its not a perfect JSONObject as ids and States doesnt have the double Quotes. Here i have the string directly but i will be getting the string dynamically. So not sure how i can add double quotes after i can get the jsonString. Need some help please.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good way i tried this: .replace("ids","\"ids\"").

Answer (score 0):

just use online http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html , just paste your string it will give string in correct escaped format.

Comment: I think OP is asking to that JSON is not in correct format. Online tools require correct json to escape.

Comment: I have validating json in Online tools and this worked fine for me.
replace("ids","\"ids\"")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good way but i am replacing ids with "ids" like:

```
jsonString.replace("ids","\"ids\"");
```